# Implementing IQueryable and ASTs for finding entities in a game

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, iqueryable

From what I understand, in some enterprise C# code there is a way to translate LINQ queries to ASTs that are then translated to SQL or something similar, using `IQueryable` and `Expression`.
This looks to me like this:

Code oblivious to DB implementation -> Black magic -> Optimized SQL

I would like to understand that black magic and apply it to a game. This is my scenario:

```
class Entity { public Vector2 position; }

class Chunk {
   const int CHUNK_SIZE = 16;
   public Vector2 position;  // chunk position is multiple of CHUNK_SIZE
   public List<Entity> entities;
}

class World {
   public Chunk[,] chunks; // Let's imagine this is a 256x256 array of chunks.
   public IEnumerable<Entity> Entities {
      get {
         return chunks.SelectMany(c => c.entities);
      }
   }
}

class SomewhereElse {
   void NotVerySmartCode() {
      var someArbitraryEntities = world.Entities
         .Where(e => e.position.x > 213 && e.position.x < 247
            && e.position.y > 198 && e.position.y < 212);

      foreach (var e in someArbitraryEntities) { // slooooooow }
   }
}
```

When `NotVerySmartCode` queries `World.Entities` the enumerator will traverse all the chunks and all the entities and perform the `Where` lambda on each one.

It is quite obvious that this code could be optimized if the `Where` lambda was executed only on the chunks whose position was within 208 < x < 256 and 192 < y < 224.

Is there a way to intelligently interpret LINQ and perform this optimization? Can I somehow implement `IQueryable` and use `Expression` in a way that would perform some black magic?

I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense, but I don't understand how LINQ queries analogous to the one above can be translated to efficient SQL.

Comment: I am not sure if I am not understanding you correctly or if you actually want to run SQL against an in-memory collection. `IQueryable` is for external queries, which yes, normally are databases, not for queries against in-memory data

Comment: Sure, you could create a layer of indirection between your optimisations and the sharp-end of your code, but IMO this would lead to a maintenance hazard down the road. At the end of the day, the efficiencies that you talk of occur because databases can make use of indexes that are tailored to the search space. As such, your time might be better spent looking at efficient ways to index/partition your search-space such as quad-trees etc.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No, I don't want to run SQL on my in-memory data, but I would like to be able to manipulate expression trees and find optimizations that way.

Comment: @spender Well, yes, exactly, I would like to optimize LINQ queries to how I store Entities. This is not a problem that is solved by a quad-tree or any other data structure, since it is trivial to find an entity at any position quickly with the current setup (just look for a chunk at a position and iterate over its entities), but that only works if the code is aware of the data structure. If all I know is that there exist some entities, and don't know that they are stored in chunks, how would I go about optimizing the naive LINQ query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, of course I've figured it out half an hour after posting a question.

```
Func<int, int> addThree = (a) => a + 3; // This compiles to IL
Expression<Func<int, int>> addTwo = (a) => a + 2; // This compiles to an AST
```

We can navigate the AST and interpret it:

```
Debug.Log(addTwo.Body); // (a + 2)
Debug.Log(addTwo.Type); // Func<int, int>
Debug.Log(addTwo.Body.NodeType); // Add
Debug.Log(addTwo.Body is BinaryExpression); // True
Debug.Log(((BinaryExpression)addTwo.Body).Left.NodeType); // Parameter
Debug.Log(((BinaryExpression)addTwo.Body).Right.NodeType); // Constant
Debug.Log(((ConstantExpression)((BinaryExpression)addTwo.Body).Right).Value); // 2
```

We can compile the AST:

```
return addTwo.Compile()(2); // 4
```

We could also, theoretically, detect patterns in it and optimize them.
Or we could translate them to SQL.

Basically, the information I was lacking was that a lambda expression, when assigned to an `Expression`, becomes something other than when assigned to a delegate.

Comment: I still don't know where you're headed with this, but have an upvote for your self-answer.

Comment: @spender thanks. Well, the idea is that a programmer who wants to filter some data (in this case, the entities), shouldn't have to know in what way the data is stored. They ideally should be able to specify some requirements for the data they want and the system will work out what is the optimal way of reaching the data. Basically, I want to apply the IDEA of a database.